# Excel cells show 0 instead of blank

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I've been working on some formulas and in cells instead of blank it shows 0.

[image: Look here.]

Code looks like this `=IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH(A2;B$2:B$100;0));"";A2)`.

I have tried IFERROR and it set to general.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your formula, when A2 is blank and the match fails, eventually resolves to

```
=A2
```

If A2 is empty, Excel will return a `0` in that circumstance.

One way around it is to explicitly test A2 for being empty, which is the same as having a "null string"

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH(A2,B$2:B$100,0)),"",IF(A2="","",A2))
```

or

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH(A2,B$2:B$100,0)),"",IF(ISBLANK(A2),"",A2))
```